# format text in java print ticket

Tags: java, printing, format

[image: print in LOG]
[image: SET TEXT TEXBOX]

Hello, I have the following problem, I'm trying to print a ticket, when printing in the `LOG` it shows everything well but when I pass the string to a text field this format is lost, I'll leave an example

```
    double total = 0;
    f.format("%-15s %5s %10s\n", "Item", "Qty", "Price");
    f.format("%-15s %5s %10s\n", "----", "---", "-----");
    for (Detalle detalle: results) {
        f.format("%-15.15s %5d %10.2f\n", detalle.getItem(), detalle.getCantidad(),(double) detalle.getValor());
        total += detalle.getValor();
    }
    f.format("%-15s %5s %10.2f\n", "Tax", "", total * 0.06);
    f.format("%-15s %5s %10s\n", "", "", "-----");
    f.format("%-15s %5s %10.2f\n", "Total", "",
            total * 1.06);

    msg = f.toString();
    System.out.print(f);
    System.out.print(msg);
    textImprimir.setText(f.toString());
```

Comment: A fixed width font on the text area or use html based table or an appropriate table structure.  Which UI framework are you using?

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43727494/format-jlabel-jtextbox/43727707#43727707) or [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25922360/how-to-preserve-command-prompts-formatting-inside-a-jtextarea-or-some-other-ty/25922802#25922802),

Comment: Android Studio UI

Comment: A fixed width font is Monospace, Courier.

Comment: gracias ahora todo se ve ok

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use different fonts in the textfield and the LOG,

The font in the LOG uses the same space for every letter, the textfields ones doesn't

Comment: when I print the text on a thermal printer which format will prevail ?, I still do not have the printer, I'll buy it soon

Comment: i guess that will be dependant on the print functionality you are using.